# c# sonarQube some reported by sonar-scanner but not with sonar-msbuild-scanner

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube

I was running the sonar msbuild scanner with multiple rules, some requiring a build and some that do not
I then ran the sonar scanner, only on the subset of rules that do not require building 
The result was some that issues got correctly reported when running the non msbuild scanner and those issues were not reported when running the msbuild scanner

I then updated to the latest sonarQube c# plugin and ran the analysis with the msbuild scanner (not feasible with scanner) and got the same observation: some issues got missed despite the rule being enabled

Example:

- no complain about args which is not used with the latest plugin and msbuild scanner (the rule is still there and active though )
  "     `static void Main(string[] args)` "
- the unused parameter is however reported when running with an older plugin and the non msbuild scanner

Has anybody experienced this please?

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to ask here

Comment: multiple things 
- does anybody know why some rules do not seem to be applied when I use sonar-msbuild-scanner ?
- would someone thing of something I may be doing wrong ?

I have just experience something else

I did
- SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin
- Msbuild /t:rebuild
- SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
and then
- SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin
- Msbuild
- SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end


I got different results between the 2 and for more issues reported in the 2nd case